# Display a .phtml Block in another Theme

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I'd like to display a block which is currently working on my custom theme on base theme section.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('fblogin/fblogin') ->setTemplate('fblogin/bt_fblogin.phtml')->toHtml() ; ?>
```

I'm using a one-page checkout plugin and it is installed in base theme folder, How can i Display the above block there.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy file from base to your theme.

and add below code to your phtml file where you want to add

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('fblogin/fblogin')->setTemplate('fblogin/bt_fblogin.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: I've tried that but it's showing a blank page.

Comment: Make sure your 'fblogin/bt_fblogin.phtml' in your theme where you are trying to call?

Comment: I've copied   **fblogin/bt_fblogin.phtml** to base/template and i need to display it inside base/template/onestepcheckout/loginform.phtml

Comment: And when i tried to display that block outside the form I got **Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object**

Comment: Thanks @Prashant it worked, I forgot to copy a plugin file in lib folder